# How can I can make my text truncate to work on continuous responsive?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, truncate

I made a text truncate which check if overflow so it will show the `ReadMore` button, need to make it continuous reading the element height so it can show & remove the overflow activity on responsive now you can see in code sandbox it's need to be re-render to read the height but client want continuously work when he put the window in responsive view without the re-render

code sandbox demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/aged-breeze-bbqel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign the code you wrote to check for overflow and display ReadMore button as function to window resize handler. It will trigger each time a resize event occurs.

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function(event){
  // Check for overflow
});
```

Place the above code in useEffect onMount and add removeEventListener in the unMount part so that it wont be performed even when the component is not there.

Comment: little confused can you edit my codesandbox code?

Comment: I put this on the render because using functional component, hopefully, it's not going to affect anything?

Comment: Great! Also as i was saying make sure to remove the Event listener on component unMount you can check that by adding a console statement inside event listener call back.